# Check if a program has stopped working in Windows using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am trying to create a python program that can detect if a particular program I use stops working so it can then notify me that it has stopped working.

Currently, I have this:

```
def isresponding(name):
    os.system('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %s" /FI "STATUS eq not responding" > tmp.txt' % name)
    tmp = open('tmp.txt', 'r')
    a = tmp.readlines()
    print(a)
    tmp.close()
    if a[-1].split()[0] == name:
        print("True")
        return True
    else:
        print("False")
        return False
```

The problem with this code is this it checks if the program is not responding however, my program gives this instead but doesn't say not responding

[image: Image showing error]

Is there any way python that can detect if this happens or do I need to use something else?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My approach: find the difference between working and non-working states in the process counters in `psutil` and periodically check if the counter is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try `psutil` or `subprocess`. If you want to dive into *Windows*, I recommend `pywin32`

```py
from psutil import process_iter

for element in process_iter():
    print(element)
```

Output:

```
sutil.Process(pid=0, name='System Idle Process', status='running')
psutil.Process(pid=4, name='System', status='running')
psutil.Process(pid=100, name='Registry', status='running', started='2022-04-20 00:27:07')
psutil.Process(pid=316, name='fontdrvhost.exe', status='running', started='2022-04-20 00:27:16')
psutil.Process(pid=436, name='smss.exe', status='running', started='2022-04-20 00:27:09')
psutil.Process(pid=560, name='dllhost.exe', status='running', started='2022-04-22 12:05:10')
psutil.Process(pid=688, name='svchost.exe', status='running', started='2022-04-20 00:27:18')
psutil.Process(pid=700, name='csrss.exe', status='running', started='2022-04-20 00:27:15')
...
```